# AsyncTask return null value

Tags: android, android-asynctask, dropbox-api

I have problem in getting dropbox shareLink. I have tried changed the code based on some answer here, but the output still the same. I do not know which part of this codes are wrong

Here is my code:

```
public class loadMetadata extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private DropboxAPI<?> mApi;
    private String mPath;
    //private UploadRequest mRequest;
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] fnames;
    String shareAddress = null;
    //private int i = 0;

    public loadMetadata(Context context, DropboxAPI<?> api, String dropboxPath) {
        // We set the context this way so we don't accidentally leak activities
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();

        //mFileLen = file.length();
        mApi = api;
        mPath = dropboxPath;
        //mFile = file;
    }

        protected String doInBackground(String... String) {
            String shareAddress = null;
            int i = 0;
              try {
                    Entry dropboxDir = mApi.metadata(mPath, 1000, null, true, null);


                    for (Entry ent : dropboxDir.contents)
                    {
                        if (!ent.isDir) {
                            DropboxLink shareLink = mApi.share(ent.path);
                            //shareAddress = shareLink.url.replaceFirst("https://www", "https://dl");
                            shareAddress = shareLink.url;
                            Log.d("Dropbox","dropbox share link " + shareAddress);
                            //fnames[i] = shareAddress;
                        } 
                        i++;
                    }



                } catch (DropboxException e) {

                }

            return shareAddress;


    }  


        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            if(result != null)
            {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }        
}
```

Comment: what you are getting here Log.d("Dropbox","dropbox share link " + shareAddress); did you got address or null?

Comment: Why are you looping through all the contents if you're only going to return the last one?

Comment: Really so difficult to handle exeptions.

Comment: This question isn't very clear. According to the title, the issue is that your `AsyncTask` is "returning" null, but `AsyncTask`s don't return anything, right? Do you mean that the parameter to `onPostExecute` is null? Does the logging show that you're getting share links? Are you catching any exceptions?

Comment: Actually, there are a lot of code fragments I have created. So, it is hard to trace one by one. Based on code above, I just want to know if the code is properly running. I know it will return more than one result, but I just want to ensure that at least this code can capture even one value. I will modify this code later after I have there problem is known. @m0skit0

Comment: @Hardik For Log.d, I don't know what happened. I'm running on emulator. There are no result printed on LogCat. There only information I can see on LogCat is System.

Comment: @smarx yup, you're right. Actually, the system is crashed if I execute this code. The error on LogCat print Java.Lang.NullPointerException which is I believe I'm trying to Toast null value.

Comment: @user2920725 Your code checks that `result` is not null before calling `Toast.makeText`, so it seems unlikely that the `NullPointerException` is coming from that line. You're telling me you get an exception but it doesn't give you a line number and stack trace?